# How can I transform my data properly to the required type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
labels1 = [{'yMax': u'780.797833935018', 'xMax': u'587.5438596491229', 'xMin': u'366.84210526315786',
                'yMin': u'613.9097472924188', 'id': '1', 'name': 'start'},
               {'yMax': u'244.37184115523468', 'xMax': u'2096.6666666666665', 'xMin': u'2057.8947368421054',
                'yMin': u'125.16606498194946', 'id': '2', 'name': ''},
               {'yMax': u'146.02707581227438', 'xMax': u'533.859649122807', 'xMin': u'477.1929824561403',
                'yMin': u'119.2057761732852', 'id': u'3', 'name': ''},
               {'yMax': u'336.7563176895307', 'xMax': u'838.0701754385965', 'xMin': u'775.438596491228',
                'yMin': u'238.4115523465704', 'id': u'4', 'name': ''},
               {'yMax': u'235.43140794223828', 'xMax': u'214.73684210526315', 'xMin': u'187.89473684210526',
                'yMin': u'149.0072202166065', 'id': u'5', 'name': ''},
               {'yMax': u'420.20036101083036', 'xMax': u'456.3157894736842', 'xMin': u'426.49122807017545',
                'yMin': u'330.79602888086646', 'id': u'6', 'name': 'end'}

               ]
```

My data is a `list of dictionaries` as the example shared above just more dictionaries in the list. That example has them hardcoded but in the real situation they're in a txt file, the issue I have is making them work properly read from the txt file in that format.

The data as  they look in my .txt file

```
{'yMax': u'156', 'xMax': u'4802', 'xMin': u'4770','yMin': u'141', 'id': '1', 'name': ''}
{'yMax': u'157', 'xMax': u'4895', 'xMin': u'4810','yMin': u'141', 'id': '2', 'name': ''}
```

The thing is further processing worked on the hardcoded version but didn't when I read them from a file, because i'm probably reading them as `strings` not as dictionaries and not sure what the most efficient way to fix that is, I tried reading them as `json.load` or line by line, then using `re.findall(r'\d+', str(labels1))` to get the numbers and appending a dict  1 by 1 but it's a hasstle and didn't even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when you read file, the content is saved to `string` variable. You can use `eval` function on this variable, to convert it to exactly what you want. [Documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)
But be aware, that `eval` [isn't secure, so consider also this solution](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

In your concrete case it should look like:

```
with open("my_file_with_formated_data", "r") as file:
    my_data = file.read()
    labels1 = eval(my_data)
```

You could also use [`ast literal eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead of `eval` to make sure everything is safe.

Comment: eval can be very dangerous, especially when working with data from untrusted sources. In the given case, I think [ast's literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) would be a better choice

Comment: @Qback thanks, but would a more specific edit to your answer on how to treat my exact case be possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ast` which is more safe than eval. read more: [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
import ast

file = open("file.txt", 'r')

for line in file.readlines():
    dicObj = ast.literal_eval(line.strip('\n'))
    print(isinstance(dicObj, dict))
```

> > True